# Primefaces DataExporter exporterFunction

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Looking for some help with this.  Trying to use this feature (latest 6.0 version) in a complicated dataTable as some of our columns have nested/multiple elements and this seemed perfect to control the Export output.  The docs state it needs to resolve to a MethodExpression which takes in an instance of a column.  No matter what syntax/method implementation I try I always get an error.  I'm currently stuck with EL version 2.0 (Weblogic 10.3.6 JSF 2.0) so am unable to use parentheses.

Firstly I tried just a normal valueExpression.  This resolves to the firstName which then errors to say it's not a methodExpression

```
<p:column headerText="first" exportFunction="#{vo.firstName}">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <!--Lots of other non exporter stuff here-->
                    <h:outputText value="#{vo.firstName}"/>    
                </h:panelGroup>
</p:column>
```

Then I tried.  Same issue.

```
<p:column headerText="first" exportFunction="#{vo['firstName']}">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <!--Lots of other non exporter stuff here-->
                    <h:outputText value="#{vo.firstName}"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
</p:column>
```

When I wrote an actual method:

```
public String showFirstName(Column column) {
        return "test";
    }
```

And used like:

```
<p:column headerText="first" exportFunction="#{bean.showFirstName}">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <!--Lots of other non exporter stuff here-->
                    <h:outputText value="#{vo.firstName}"/>    
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
```

This errored with

```
bean does not have the property 'showFirstName'
```

If I add parentheses to the method:

```
<p:column headerText="first" exportFunction="#{bean.showFirstName()}">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <!--Lots of other non exporter stuff here-->
                        <h:outputText value="#{vo.firstName}"/>    
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:column>
```

I get this:

```
Error Parsing: #{bean.showFirstName()}
Encountered "(" at line 1, column 26. Was expecting one of: "}" ... "." ... "[" ... ">" ... "gt" ... "<" ... "lt" ... ">=" ... "ge" ... "<=" ... "le" ... "==" ... "eq" ... "!=" ... "ne" ... "&&" ... "and" ... "||" ... "or" ... "*" ... "+" ... "-" ... "?" ... "/" ... "div" ... "%" ... "mod" ...
```

Any guidance much appreciated.  I have a feeling my issue is with the EL version.

Also do you think it would be a good idea to have another attribute of ExportValue.  This could just take normal a valueExpression and would be very simple to use.

Comment: In the last example, your method signature is not in line with the EL. You **can** use 'parentheses' but not using a parameter. Your EL should be `#{bean.showFirstName()}` and your method should accordingly not have a parameter `public String showFirstName() {`

Comment: And if you correct the method to not have a parameter and leave the parentheses out of the EL? If that does not work, I think your EL version is really old

Comment: If I do that I get 'The class `com.MyBean' does not have the property 'showFirstName'.`

Comment: For completeness if I change the name of the method to `getShowFirstName` I get the error `annot convert test of type class java.lang.String to class javax.el.MethodExpression`